# Series convergence test question.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I am reading some analysis textbook proof that compares Cauchy's and Dalambert's tests for series convergence.

[image]

Can you explain how  in the second line it became $\leq$  ?

Comment: What does [this symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0InaG.jpg) mean?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Sorry I  sceenshoted from by book which is armenian,That means  from that follows.

Comment: Armenian looks like a beautiful language, but please [add some more detail](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for sequences $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\langle c_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$, if $b_n < c_n$ holds then the best that can be said about their limit superiors is that $\overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} b_n \leq \overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} c_n$.

To see why strict inequality may not hold, consider the sequences $b_n=1$ for all $n$ and $c_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. Here for every $n$, we have $b_n < c_n$. But, it can be easily verified that in this case, $\overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} b_n = \overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} c_n$. Hence, we do not have $\overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} b_n < \overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} c_n$.

Let us consider your example. Assuming that $n_0$ is a constant that does not depend on $n$, for every $n$,  $\sqrt[n]{a_n} $ is strictly less than $(D+\epsilon) \sqrt[n]{a_{n_0}(D+\epsilon)^{-n_0}}$. However, it may be the case that the limit superior of the sequence of the left is equal to the limit superior of the sequence on the right, as in the example given above. Hence, the best that can be asserted about the limit superiors of these sequences is that,

$$\overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \overline{\lim}\limits_{n\ \to \infty} (D+\epsilon) \sqrt[n]{a_{n_0}(D+\epsilon)^{-n_0}} = (D+\epsilon)$$

Comment: Fantastic! @SubinPulari